# Insert a row in Excel by analyzing the values

Tags: excel, insert, row, vba

I have a huge spreadsheet with number and text.
The first column looks like this:

```
1111
1111
2222
2222
2222
3333
3333
3333
```

I would like to insert a blank row where the new unique number starts from. ie when 222222 starts after 111 I want to insert a blank row.

Comment: Might be wrong, but I think you'll need VBA to do this. Are you willing to add the Excel-VBA label, or are you only interested in non-VBA solutions?

Comment: hi Rick yes please do let let me know the vba code if there is no other shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for.

```
Sub InsertRows()
Dim i, RowVal1, RowVal2
i = 1
Do
RowVal1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
RowVal2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
If RowVal1 <> RowVal2 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
i = i + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Loop While (RowVal2 <> "")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem crops up often enough that I wished VBA allowed higher order functions so Insert could be replaced with just a delegate.

```
Sub SeparateByID(ByRef rng as Range, ByVal id_col as Variant)

    Dim row_count as Integer
    row_count = rng.Rows.Count

    Dim last_id As Variant
    last_id = rng.cells(row_count , id_col).value

    Dim row_index as Integer
    For row_index = row_count To 1 Step -1

        Dim crnt_id As Variant
        crnt_id = rng.cells(row_index, id_col).value

        If last_id <> crnt_id Then 

            rng.cells(row_index + 1, id_col).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            last_id = crnt_id 

        End If

    Next row_index 

End Sub
```

Note: The range should be sorted beforehand.

Some attempt to implement delegates...

```
Sub InsertNewRow(rng as Range)

    rng.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

End Sub

Sub DoBetweenIDs(ByRef rng as Range, ByVal id_col as Variant, ByVal delegate As String)

    Dim row_count as Integer
    row_count = rng.Rows.Count

    Dim last_id As Variant
    last_id = rng.cells(row_count , id_col).value

    Dim row_index as Integer
    For row_index = row_count To 1 Step -1

        Dim crnt_id As Variant
        crnt_id = rng.cells(row_index, id_col).value

        If last_id <> crnt_id Then 

            Application.Run delegate, rng.cells(row_index + 1, id_col)
            last_id = crnt_id

        End If

    Next row_index 

End Sub
```